# Kubuntu installation while using RTX3090 leads to black screen -> Kubuntu is still running

Tags: ubuntu, crash, nvidia, live, rtx

I have a fresh Kubuntu 20.04 LTS installation on our lab server.
Everything in the installation process worked fine.
After installation the system boot but i only get a black screen.
Imho nouveau crashes bc of the unknown RTX3090, that's what the live system tells me when i try to start it without reduced graphics.

My question is: How can i fix that problem using the live system?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Nouveau was indeed the problem and it took only a few steps to make the system running.

1. Restart System
2. Press Shift multiple times until you reach the grub menu.

Follow [this](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/) instructions for fixing Nouveau in grub to start the Kubuntu session.

Finally install the latest Nvidia driver.